# make updates static lib archive even if newer than pre-requisites

Tags: makefile, archive, prerequisites

I am building a static library from source files foo.c, bar.c and baz.c
Even though the library is timestamped newer than foo.o, bar.o and baz.o
it still gets rebuilt every time I run make.
here is the Makefile

```
CC      = gcc $(CCFLAGS)
CCFLAGS = -std=gnu17 -mtune=corei7 -flto -fopenmp -pthread -Wall -pedantic -O3 -I../include
#LDFLAGS = -L../lib -lm -ldds -ldealerV2
LDFLAGS = --verbose

SRCS = foo.c bar.c baz.c
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCS) )
LIBRARY = libfoo.a

library : $(OBJS)
    ar -rcs $(LIBRARY) $?
    ar -t $(LIBRARY)
    touch -c $(LIBRARY)

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<

clean :
        rm -f *.o a.out
```

now setup the initial conditions

```
$ make clean
rm -f *.o a.out
$ touch *.c
$ ls -l
total 48
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21  3742 Dec  9 14:02 bar.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21  3916 Dec  9 14:02 baz.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21  3220 Dec  9 14:02 foo.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21 29668 Dec  9 14:02 libfoo.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21   618 Dec  9 13:58 Makefile
```

---

### Now do the first make -- updates libfoo.a as it should

```
$ make
gcc -std=gnu17 -mtune=corei7 -flto -fopenmp -pthread -Wall -pedantic -O3 -I../include -c -o foo.o foo.c
gcc -std=gnu17 -mtune=corei7 -flto -fopenmp -pthread -Wall -pedantic -O3 -I../include -c -o bar.o bar.c
gcc -std=gnu17 -mtune=corei7 -flto -fopenmp -pthread -Wall -pedantic -O3 -I../include -c -o baz.o baz.c
ar -rcs libfoo.a foo.o bar.o baz.o
ar -t libfoo.a
foo.o
bar.o
baz.o
touch -c libfoo.a
```

---------------------------------- show the current status ---------------------

```
$ ls -l
total 84
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21  3742 Dec  9 14:02 bar.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21 10256 Dec  9 14:03 bar.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21  3916 Dec  9 14:02 baz.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21 12616 Dec  9 14:03 baz.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21  3220 Dec  9 14:02 foo.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21  6456 Dec  9 14:03 foo.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21 29684 Dec  9 14:03 libfoo.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21   618 Dec  9 13:58 Makefile
```

---

### Now make sure that libfoo.a is newer than everything else

```
$ touch libfoo.a
$ ls -l
total 84
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21  3742 Dec  9 14:02 bar.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21 10256 Dec  9 14:03 bar.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21  3916 Dec  9 14:02 baz.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21 12616 Dec  9 14:03 baz.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21  3220 Dec  9 14:02 foo.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21  6456 Dec  9 14:03 foo.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21 29684 Dec  9 14:04 libfoo.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 greg21 greg21   618 Dec  9 13:58 Makefile
```

---

### Re-issue make. It does not rebuild the .o files, then
Why does it not say that libfoo.a is uptodate ?

```
$ make
ar -rcs libfoo.a foo.o bar.o baz.o
ar -t libfoo.a
foo.o
bar.o
baz.o
touch -c libfoo.a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recipe for your target called `library` does not create a file called `library`, so the target is always out of date. Turn `library` into `$(LIBRARY)` and the target will actually be your libfoo.a file and its timestamp will be considered.

```
$(LIBRARY) : $(OBJS)
    ar -rcs $(LIBRARY) $?
    ar -t $(LIBRARY)
    touch -c $(LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Such a blind spot. I feel like a doofus. Thank you.

Comment: If you run `make --trace` (or, if your version is too old to support this, `make -d`) then make will show you exactly why it decides to rebuild things.